# module.exports object spread works intermittently

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm having an issue using `module.exports = {}` in one of my project files.

The file contains many functions which are exported as named exports, but also contains an object spread. It looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...DEFAULT_METHODS,
    methodDefinedAbove,
    anotherFunction,
    moreFunctionsStill,
}
```

When I import from this file elsewhere in the project. The imports work fine. I can import both statically named functions, like :

```
import { methodDefinedAbove } from '../../theFileWithExports';
```

as well as functions that are defined in the DEFAULT_METHODS object, like :

```
import { definedInDefaultMethods } from '../../theFileWithExports';
```

This works fine in dozens of files in my project.  Today I added a new file and the import does not work.  When I remove the ...DEFAULT_METHODS spread,  it does work.  But I can't figure out why this works in dozens of places and would just break for a new file.  The new file is a sibling of other files with working imports.

I can even hack a workaround in by importing the function I want in another file and saving it as a static class variable,  then importing that class into the component and using it's static method.

Comment: Can you show us how you import it in case it is broken? What are you doing differently from other source files?

Comment: FYI, combining `module.exports` and named ES imports is a recipe for future broken code. There is no official specification for interop like this. It would be much better to use ES `export`.

Comment: I can only second loganfsmyth. Use proper ES6 module `export` syntax instead of `module.exports`.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)